# List of post quantum cryptography protocols

Tags: encryption, protocol-design, post-quantum-cryptography

What are the post quantum cryptography protocols that have been proposed until now?

I know about McEliece cryptosystem, and LWE scheme. What are the others? Can you provide me a list or a website containing such list?

Comment: code based, (R)LWE based, lattice based and hash based. Those are the four core problems of most PQ crypto schemes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to vote to close this question. The question asks for a reference recommendation which may get outdated rather soon and thus will be an invaluable or even misleading ressource for others looking for the same thing in the future, especially as this field seems to get some traction now after the NSA said that they now move to PQ crypto for Suite B.

Comment: @SEJPM: There's also Multivariate and Elliptic Curve Isogeny.  In addition, (R)LWE is a subset of "Lattice based"

Comment: @SEJPM it appears illogical but in English 'invaluable' is actually extremely *good*. You want 'valueless' or 'worthless'; or perhaps 'unhelpful'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a pedantic point: be careful with terminology: there currently are no Post-Quantum "*protocols*" (TLS, S/MIME, CMP, etc). From your question, I'm assuming you are interested in PQ "*schemes*", or PQ "*primitives*" (XMSS, R-LWE, etc). This may seem like nit-picking, but we can expect NIST to standardize *primitives* in the next **3 - 5 years**, *protocols* will take longer than that!

---

Now for your actual question. As @SEJPM points out, the research is still very young and is rapidly changing, so any links to actual schemes will very quickly go out of date. What I will do instead is link to the **organizations that you should be following**.

### NIST

- [Link to their talk from the recent PQCrypto2016 conference](https://pqcrypto2016.jp/data/pqc2016_nist_announcement.pdf) outlining their upcoming call for applications for candidate PQ signature and encryption schemes.
- [See their February 2016 report](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/nistir-8105/nistir_8105_draft.pdf), basically a "What we know at this point".
- `pqc-forum@nist.gov` is the mail-list for discussion of post-quantum schemes and their standardization. This went live *very* recently so I can't find any references to it online, but you can get yourself onto it by sending an empty email to `pqc-forum-request@nist.gov` with `subject:subscribe`

### NSA

- [See their Suite B page](https://www.nsa.gov/ia/programs/suiteb_cryptography/) (at time of writing, it was last updated in August 2015).
- [See their January 2016 announcement of the replacement of Suite B.](https://cryptome.org/2016/01/CNSA-Suite-and-Quantum-Computing-FAQ.pdf)

### PQCrypto Project

- Group funded by the European Union to research and recommend PQ schemes.
- [pqcrypto.eu.org](https://pqcrypto.eu.org/)

### IETF / IRTF's Crypto Forum Research Group (CFRG)

- [Draft standard for XMSS hash-based signatures](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-xmss-hash-based-signatures/).
- [irtf.org/cfrg](https://irtf.org/cfrg)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably fairly thorough.. http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/nistir-8105/nistir_8105_draft.pdf

Comment: @all: Please see Mike Ounsworth's answer for a more complete discussion of this same topic.

Answer (score 1):

In public key cryptography,three schemes are quantum-secure:

1. [Lattice based cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice-based_cryptography) like NTRUEncrypt and LWE; based on lattices
2. [code-based cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Code-based_cryptography) like McEliece cryptosystem; based on information theory
3. [multivariate cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_cryptography) like Hidden Fields Equations

and in symmetric encryption like AES,if you choose a long key;you are safe against quantum computer and NSA!

for future reading:[Quanta magazine link](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20150908-quantum-safe-encryption/) and [post-quantum cryptography book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540887010)

Comment: you're missing at least "hash based" (for signatures) and "elliptic curve isogeny based" (for encryption), additionally to all those reference problems introduced with all the FHE schemes...

Comment: Also missing "braid group based".
@SEJPM: Also "isogeny based" will most likely never make it to a protocol, since underlying assumptions are supposed to be to weak. This may only have pedagogical interest (as stated by the authors).